# Member server: Can it have a mailbox server or is that only for domain controllers?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, mailbox

If I join a Windows Server 2003 machine as a member server to another Window Server 2008 machine that is a DC, can I have a mailbox server in the Window Server 2003 member server?  Or is that only for DCs?  Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install a mailbox server (presumably Exchange Server) on any domain joined server.

Comment: To add to that, Microsoft recommends *not* having it on a DC, unless it is an SBS.